# Словно гвоздями. Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Ветер словно гвоздями прошивал тело. Нужно выделить запятыми оборот "словно гвоздями"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ветер словно гвоздями прошивал тело.

Запятых в этом предложении не требуется.

Comment: Почему не требуется?